# View Isolated storage files of windows 8 metro app

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, isolatedstorage

I am saving some data and writing some xml file to isolated storage of Windows 8 metro apps. As I have made some apps in windows phone we can see these isolated storage file by isotool and Windows Phone power tools. Is there anyway I can see and explore my files saved by my apps in windows 8 metro app?

Answer (score 6):

Windows 8 does not use Isolated storage like sliverlight/Windows Phone - instead, files written are simply written to a special folder assigned to the app (per user).

To wit:

```
C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Packages
```

Look for your package name (in the manifest) and you will find it there - that folder will be the name of the folder the files are located under. e.g.

```
C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Packages\91e643e0-f4a2-4e96-99cd-b1f1b13897aa_te6ss58atez9j
```